# On-the-fly C++ compiler for system-independent program distribution

Tags: java, c++, compilation

The main reason why inhouse software projects in my company are mostly done in Java is that Java programs are independent of the host machine architecture and this gives a lot of flexibility for distributing the application to the departments internationally.

We need to start a new application which does a lot of number crunching and I would like to use the C++ libs and code that we have available (also I like C++ better).

Now I wondered why there is not some software which acts like the Java JIT-compiler in the following sense:

1. Perform compilation until [intermediate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation) such as LLVM IR
2. Distribute packed intermediate representation to client computers
3. Compile on the local machine once
4. Execute

This would combine several benefits of Java and C++:

- Optimization for the local machine architecture (like the JIT does)
- Distributing an operating system independent version of the software (Java)
- Execution of the program without a virtual machine in between (C++)

What are the reasons something like this isn't done?

Comment: performance, mainly. C++ compiled directly on the target platform is generally much faster than languages which rely on an intermediate language, such as Java and the .NET family, because the compilation is more efficient and there's no interpretation of anything required at runtime. It's horses for courses - people use C++ for O/S level stuff and performance-critical things like games, and they use Java/.NET for LOB apps etc. because memory management is a bit easier, there are more language features and you can target multiple platforms. In other words, you use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @ADyson the idea is to do compilation on the target platform.

Comment: I don't know a huge amount about compilers but I would strongly suspect the intermediate compilation step would still come at a performance cost. Compiling for a specific target allows the compiler to make optimisations o the source code which can take advantage of the features of the target platform. If you compile to some generic intermediary, there's a good chance that subtlety could be lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chief reason why this isn't done for high-performance applications is that the last bit of performance comes at a rather high price. A modern JIT is a decent compromise between compile-time delays and quality of code generated.

Instead, modern C++ compilers (including Intel and GCC) can statically compile for multiple alternative architecture variants and choose the right variant when the program is loaded. It turns out you don't have that many variants to consider anyway. Practically, you're looking at AVX (none/1/2).

And if your compiler doesn't do that, a cheap hand-rolled alternative is to put the alternative variants in a bundle of dynamically loaded libraries, and pick the right library at load time. With MSVC's delay-loaded libraries this can be just as transparent. You just hook the actual library load to choose `MathAVX.DLL` instead of `MathSSE.DLL`.

Of course, for the real high-performance applications you can just say "64 bits, AVX2" or "CUDA, compute capability 6+". For such applications, software defines the hardware and not vice versa.